# Is there a generalization of the ODE Comparison Theorem to n dimensional systems such as this one?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems

Is the following theorem true? If so, under what conditions? If not, why not?

For any finite set of points $S$, let $conv(S)$ denote the convex hull of $S$.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^n $ and $g_k:\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ for $k =1,2,3,...,m $.

Consider the following systems of ordinary differential equations:

$$\dot{x}(t) = f(x,t),\, x(t_i) = x_i, x \in \mathbb{R}^n, t \in \mathbb{R} $$

and

$$ \dot{y}_k(t) = g_k(y_k,t),\, y_k(t_i) = y_{ik}, y_k \in \mathbb{R}^n, t \in \mathbb{R} $$ for $k = 1,2,3,...,m $.

Suppose that $\forall p \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}, \,f(p) \in conv(\{g_1(p),g_2(p),...g_m(p)\})  $. Suppose additionally that $x_i \in conv(\{y_{i1},y_{i2},...,y_{im}\})$

Then $\forall t>t_i: x(t) \in conv(\{y_1(t),y_2(2),...,y_m(t)\})$

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ODE Comparison Theorem (kind of language barrier, sorry), but could you be more explicit at this point? Was this generalization described somewhere else or is it your idea?

Comment: The theorem I am referring to is stated in the introduction here:

http://www.emis.de/journals/NSJOM/Papers/40_1/NSJOM_40_1_055_056.pdf

It is itself a minor generalization of "Gronwall's inequality", described here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall's_inequality

The generalization I am asking about was described by a professor of mine as something he believed should be true. I also think the generalization seems like it should be true -- it seems like a natural extension of the one-dimensional case.